# Pattern3 code not working for me in Python3 (but I know the code works for others), does it matter that I'm using a Mac?

Tags: python, twitter, anaconda, text-mining

I continue to get the error, "'<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'", but none of the fellow students are receiving this error. This code was provided to us, so I know I didn't do something wrong. My only guess is that it needs something different when it is run on a mac vs windows?

```
%%time
from pattern.web import Twitter, hashtags
engine = Twitter(language="en")

indexid = set() 
tweets =[]

prev = None
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    for tweet in engine.search("stock market bull or bear", start=prev, count= 20, cached=False):
        print(f" hashtag = {hashtags(tweet.text)} text = {tweet.text}, author = {tweet.author}, date = {tweet.date} ")
        if len(tweet.text) > 0 and tweet.id not in indexid:
            tweets.append(tweet.text)
            indexid.add(tweet.id)
            prev = tweet.id
print(f"Found {len(tweets)} tweets!" )
print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

The default to `engine.search` must be an integer or an id. The method is defined as follows:

```
def search(self, query, type=SEARCH, start=1, count=10, sort=RELEVANCY, size=None, cached=False, **kwargs):
    """ Returns a list of results from Twitter for the given query.
        - type : SEARCH,
        - start: Result.id or int,
        - count: maximum 100.
        There is a limit of 150+ queries per 15 minutes.
    """
```

So in this case, all you need to do is initialize prev to start at `1`, instead of `None` (which is what is causing your error).

```
prev = 1
for i in range(5):
    ...
```

Which resulted in:

```
Found 25 tweets!
```